# Methods for cutting glass

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, glass, ceramics

I am trying to find the easiest way to cut a thick glass pattern (glass thickness of 1-3 mm thick) without breaking. I am considering laser cutting but I don't know if I can cut glass of this thickness. Can anyone suggest an easy way to cut curved shapes precisely into glass?

Comment: 1-3 mm won‘t be a problem to cut with a laser

Comment: Also possible to use a waterjet cutter. (also 1-3 mm is not really thick as far as the watejet is concerned try 300 mm)

Comment: I recently used a diamond granite cutting blade on my angle grinder, it worked fantastically well (just be careful, it cuts almost too easy;).

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your cut geometry, you can use a simple handheld glass scorer, and follow-up with a set of snapping pliers. The pliers have a slight bevel which will cleanly separate the glass. 

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-5-in-Glass-Cutter-8501H/100169741

https://www.homedepot.com/p/KNIPEX-7-1-4-in-Glass-Breaking-Pliers-91-31-180/305647641?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD25T%7C25-1_HAND+TOOLS%7CNA%7CPLA%7c71700000034127224%7c58700003933021546%7c92700044942409617&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIl_G05aTl4gIVD9tkCh36MAtwEAQYASABEgK5A_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 1):

Waterjet cutters work like a charm up to 5mm. I have cut 'fireproof' glass of 4mm and it came out very well.

Comment: Don't waterjet cutters work well over greater thicknesses than 5mm?

Comment: At absurd speeds like 800-1000mm/min I was able to cut through 4mm glass fairly easily. I presume it would be fair for us to be talking inches instead of milimiters in case of lower cutting speeds.

Comment: I was wondering if you had read the comment by Jooja above that mentions 300mm is considered thick....

Comment: @SolarMike it greatly depends on the waterjet cutter and the abrasive medium used. Much like different lasers have different results. But yeah i have cut glass building bricks with waterjets.

Comment: What type of precision can you get though?

Answer (score 0):

1-3 mm is perfectly doable with a cheap-o, off the shelf, carbide glass cutter. So long as your shapes are generally large sweeping curves (i.e. few acute corners), you can use something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078YS9KJY) to score then glass, then something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005I67ZMW) to cleanly snap the piece.